# Claims Authentication Unexpected Error in Developer Dashboard

Tags: claims-based-auth

The error below is listed in the developer dashboard in our environments. We have recently changed to claims authentication. The contentdatabase has been converted from classical authentication. We have run the commands

```
$WebAppName = "xxxx"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$wa.MigrateUsers($true)
```

The problem still persists.

> Claims Authentication Unexpected g220 No windows identity for
>   domain\user

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CurrentClaimsUserIsBoxAdministrator(IClaimsIdentity identity)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CurrentUserIsBoxAdministrator()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.CurrentUserIgnoreThrottle()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPManagedCodeInterop.CanCurrentUserIgnoreThrottle(Guid siteId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureFieldMap()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetRawValue(String fieldname, Int32 iIndex, Boolean bThrow)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_Item(String fieldName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl.get_ItemFieldValue()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.RichHtmlField.RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.BaseRichField.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.RichHtmlField.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.COMMUNITYWELCOMEPAGE_ASPX__1651535092.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error normally happens when you try to save a template however you can go through these links and solutions in them if they can help you somehow,

[Same Error and few solutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/dadc788b-05de-4ead-a38d-0d4207e3ad06)

also check if Claims to Windows Token Service is running or not

Comment: Claims to Windows Token Service was my problem. It was disabled on my search app server. Thanks!